# Hibernate não gera o banco e as tabelas no mysql

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, java-ee

Estou com problemas no meu projeto,sobre a criação do banco junto com as 
tabelas.

> ```
> jul 06, 2017 7:19:21 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
> INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.10.Final}
> jul 06, 2017 7:19:21 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
> INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
> jul 06, 2017 7:19:21 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
> INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
> jul 06, 2017 7:19:21 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
> WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
> jul 06, 2017 7:19:21 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
> INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Drogaria]
> jul 06, 2017 7:19:21 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
> INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=root, password=****}
> jul 06, 2017 7:19:21 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
> INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
> jul 06, 2017 7:19:21 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections <init>
> INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
>     at br.com.drogaria.util.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:24)
>     at br.com.drogaria.util.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:14)
>     at br.com.drogaria.main.GeraTabela.main(GeraTabela.java:9)
> Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
>     at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:271)
>     at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:233)
>     at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
>     at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
>     at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:242)
>     at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
>     at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
>     at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
>     at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
>     at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:418)
>     at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:87)
>     at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:691)
>     at br.com.drogaria.util.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:21)
>     ... 2 more
> Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Error calling Driver#connect
>     at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:106)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator$1$1.convert(BasicConnectionCreator.java:101)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.convertSqlException(BasicConnectionCreator.java:123)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:41)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:58)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.addConnections(PooledConnections.java:123)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.<init>(PooledConnections.java:42)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.<init>(PooledConnections.java:20)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections$Builder.build(PooledConnections.java:161)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildPool(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:109)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:72)
>     at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
>     at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:242)
>     at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:145)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
>     at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
>     at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:259)
>     ... 15 more
> Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'drogaria'
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1053)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4120)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4052)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:925)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1704)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1250)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2465)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2498)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2283)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:822)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:404)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:317)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:38)
>     ... 30 more
> ```

Como o meu hibernate.cfg  estar...

```
<hibernate-configuration>

<session-factory>

    <!-- Database connection settings -->
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Drogaria</property>
    <property name="connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="connection.password">ricardo</property>


     <!-- SQL dialect -->
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</property>


    <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

    <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
    <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property>

    <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>

    <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

    <mapping class="br.com.drogaria.domain.Fabricante"/>
</session-factory>
```

E o meu HibernateUtil

```
private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {


    try {           
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");     
        return configuration.buildSessionFactory( new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings( configuration.getProperties() ).build() );
    }
    catch (Throwable ex) {                
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
}

public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}
```

Uma view do meu projeto, para se ter uma ideia:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Ele está reclamando que não existe o banco de dados "drogaria"

Comment: Assim, só por desencargo, o nome do projeto ser "Trogaria" foi só um erro de digitação? Será que você também sem querer não criou a base de dados "Trogaria"?

Comment: Tipo o nome do projeto ficou esse pq eu tinha outro quando criei,não tenho base de dados chamada Trogaria ...quem tem que criar é o hibernate....eu estou seguindo esta video aua aew saca  [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3aPuNR0UNHg&t=11s]

Answer (score 1):

Encontrei a solução : eu criei a base de dados drogaria

Aew os erros não surgiram mais ...mas mesmo assim não gerava as tabelas no meu Mysql,então alterei a minha classe HibernateUtil assim :

```
public class HibernateUtil {

private static SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {

    final StandardServiceRegistry registry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
            .configure()
            .build();
    try {
        sessionFactory = new MetadataSources(registry).buildMetadata().buildSessionFactory();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy(registry);
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    return sessionFactory;

}


public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}
```

Aew  gerou as tabelas no banco =]